# Excess files inside a Safari Extension

Tags: file, safari, safari-extension

I'm currently working on a Safari Extension that adds a stylesheet and some small scripts to a site. One of those scripts has to be inserted in the html, so I've another scripts running...

```
var myScriptElement = document.createElement('script');
myScriptElement.type = 'text/javascript';
myScriptElement.src = 'http://mysite.com/myscript.js';
document.querySelector('head').appendChild(myScriptElement);
```

...that adds this to the head:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mysite.com/myscript.js"></script>
```

The problem I have is that the scripts gets loaded from my site instead of the extension folder. So what do I have to insert as source to access the extension folder?
I can't insert the script using the standard start- and end-script-extension-function.

I'm really bad in javascripting so I would appreciate if someone of you could help me! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `safari.extension.baseURI` to get the path to your extension folder. So use something like this in your injected script:

```
var myScriptElement = document.createElement('script');
myScriptElement.type = 'text/javascript';
myScriptElement.src = safari.extension.baseURI+'myscript.js';
document.querySelector('head').appendChild(myScriptElement);
```

It's worth noting that the injected script is injected into every iframe on the page too, so depending on what you are doing, you might want to ensure the above is only run `if (window == window.top)`.